# How to suppress the numbering of a single appendix chapter?

Tags: numbering, cleveref, scrbook, appendix

Consider the following LaTeX code saved in the file `Thesis.tex`:

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xr-hyper, hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The Beginning}\label{ch1}
In \cref{ch2} everything will become clear, but only with the help of \cref{app}, and specifically the results of \cref{ap1}.

\chapter{The End}\label{ch2}
That's all, folks!

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix}\label{app}

\section{Helpful Stuff}\label{ap1}
Help thy brother’s boat across, and --- lo! --- thine own has reached the shore.

\section{Hints for Further Reading}\label{ap2}
A reader lives a thousand lives before he dies. The man who never reads lives only one.

\end{document}
```

An execution of `arara Thesis` at the command prompt terminates successfully, and produces the following output:

[image: The actual output]

I would like the letter `A` next to `Appendix` to be suppressed in the table of contents as well as on page 4, but not for the appendix's two sections. Furthermore, I'd like the link to the appendix on p. 2 to read: `the appendix` rather than `appendix A`. Hopefully the following picture illustrates my intentions clearly.

[image: The desired output]

**N.B.** For some mysterious reason my screen capturing app didn't capture page 3 correctly, which in both cases should look like this:

[image: The 3rd page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new reference format for the appendix:

```latex
\crefname{appendixwithoutnumber}{appendix}{appendices}
\crefformat{appendixwithoutnumber}{#2\MakeLowercase{\appendixname}#3}
\Crefformat{appendixwithoutnumber}{#2\appendixname#3}
```

Then you can use this format for the appendix label:

`\label[appendixwithoutnumber]{app}`

To get the unnumbered appendix chapter with ToC and header entries use `\addchap`:

```latex
\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/begingroup}{\refstepcounter}
\addchap{Appendix}\label[appendixwithoutnumber]{app}
```

Example:

```latex
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xr-hyper, hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefname{appendixwithoutnumber}{appendix}{appendices}
\crefformat{appendixwithoutnumber}{#2\MakeLowercase{\appendixname}#3}
\Crefformat{appendixwithoutnumber}{#2\appendixname#3}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The Beginning}\label{ch1}
In \cref{ch2} everything will become clear, but only with the help of \cref{app}, and specifically the results of \cref{ap1}.

\chapter{The End}\label{ch2}
That's all, folks!

\appendix

\AddtoOneTimeDoHook{heading/begingroup}{\refstepcounter}
\addchap{Appendix}\label[appendixwithoutnumber]{app}

\section{Helpful Stuff}\label{ap1}
Help thy brother’s boat across, and --- lo! --- thine own has reached the shore.

\section{Hints for Further Reading}\label{ap2}
A reader lives a thousand lives before he dies. The man who never reads lives only one.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If the reference to the appendix should really be »the appendix« use

```latex
\crefname{appendixwithoutnumber}{appendix}{appendices}
\crefformat{appendixwithoutnumber}{#2the \MakeLowercase{\appendixname}#3}
\Crefformat{appendixwithoutnumber}{#2The \MakeLowercase{\appendixname}#3}
```

If »the« or »The« should be printed but not part of the link use

```latex
\crefname{appendixwithoutnumber}{appendix}{appendices}
\crefformat{appendixwithoutnumber}{the #2\MakeLowercase{\appendixname}#3}
\Crefformat{appendixwithoutnumber}{The #2\MakeLowercase{\appendixname}#3}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I modify your answer so that the references to the appendix will read: `the appendix`/`The appendix` rather than `appendix`/`Appendix`?

Comment: @EvanAad See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the following:

```latex
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\label{app}
```

In full:

```latex
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xr-hyper, hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{The Beginning}\label{ch1}
In \cref{ch2} everything will become clear, but only with the help of the \nameref{app}, and specifically the results of \cref{ap1}.

\chapter{The End}\label{ch2}
That's all, folks!

\appendix

\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\refstepcounter{chapter}
\label{app}

\section{Helpful Stuff}\label{ap1}
Help thy brother’s boat across, and --- lo! --- thine own has reached the shore.

\section{Hints for Further Reading}\label{ap2}
A reader lives a thousand lives before he dies. The man who never reads lives only one.

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]